# how to insert data for old dates in influxdb using node js?

Tags: node.js, influxdb

I tried to insert data for yesterday date in influxdb using nodejs. But it does not insert the data

if i insert data without timestamp it insert data for current timestamp. i tried with timestamp to insert for yesterday date as below

```
client_db.writeMeasurement(test.toString(), [
                            {
                                tags: {compID: compID.toString()},
                                fields: {value: compValue},
                                timestamp:'1564924108000'
                            }
```

it does not insert any data

Comment: I guess it's related to the format: InfluxDB work with nanoseconds, and your seems to be in milliseconds (my guess). Can you convert the timestamp to nanoseconds (you can use https://node-influx.github.io/function/index.html#static-function-toNanoDate) and let me know if it's working?

Comment: You will not be able to update the timestamp in InfluxDB to an older timestamp as it maintains data points with respect to current time but if you really want to update the timestamp, you can create another field/tag same as timestamp with a different name and insert the older time in that and try to workaround using that field.